# How to determine if link was clicked or visited using browser

Tags: php, html, email, url

Is there a way that I can determine if someone has clicked the link in a email vs if they typed the url in their web browser rather than clicking the link?

When I look at the weblogs I want to determine how the page was accessed, would this be a case of a unique url in the email?

Comment: Likely an XY problem. Do you notice traffic that is obviously not coming from emails?

Answer (score 0):

Unique links would be one option. Depending on your needs, a simple querystring such as `?source=email` could suffice. Of course, if somebody were to type this into the address bar, then it looks as if it were accessed from the email.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking... I basically want to run phishing test to see who clicks on the link, but I suppose clicking on the link vs typing the url has the same consequences of a legit phishing email

Answer (score -1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` If the user is coming via e-mail, you can detect it with referrer. If the user is coming from the browser (unless manipulated) the referer will be empty. [http_referer](https://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: You are mixing up the two cases. If the user comes from an e-mail, then the referrer will be empty. If the user come with a browser then the referrer will be present - unless the user typed it directly into the browser, in which case it will also be empty, so that won't help here.

Comment: You're right. I wrote this assuming you create custom url for mail. Of course, a special url (?source=email etc.) must be created for mail.